# When programming microchip in C, how do you calculate the value needed for 1 second delay

Tags: c, frequency, microchip

If it was given 187.5hz after initial Pragma configuration, it is about 1190 in order to have 1 second delay. I am stuck on how this number is calculated. Please help!

This is the initial pragma configuration

```
#pragma config   JTAGEN    = OFF    // JTAG Enable OFF (only use for '250)
#pragma config   FNOSC     = FRCPLL // Fast RC w PLL 8mHz internal rc Osc
#pragma config   FPLLIDIV  = DIV_10  // PLL in 8mHz/10 = 800 kHz
#pragma config   FPLLMUL   = MUL_15 // PLL mul 800 khz * 15 = 12 Mhz
#pragma config   FPLLODIV  = DIV_64  // PLL Out: 12MHz / 64 187.5 kHz
#pragma config   FPBDIV    = DIV_1  // Peripheral Bus Divisor
#pragma config   FCKSM     = CSECME // Clock Switch Enable, FSCM Enabled
#pragma config   POSCMOD   = OFF    // Primary osc disabled
#pragma config   IESO      = OFF    // Internal/external switch over
#pragma config   OSCIOFNC  = OFF    // CLKO Output Signal Active on the OSCO Pin
#pragma config   FWDTEN    = OFF    // Watchdog Timer Enable:
```

Here is how the 1190 comes in

```
// Delay routine
// With an 8MHz internal RC clock and settings to give a system clock
// of 187.5 kHz, the delay() function must be given about 1190 to get 1 sec
// delay:
// stopwatch: 100 complete ON/OFF pulses in 119 seconds.
// 500/((100/119)/2) = 1190
void delay(int d)
{
int i;  // Declare variable to be used in the loop

while(d)    // While d > 0
{
    i = 100;    // set i to 100 for inner loop
    while(i)    // while i > 0
    {
        i--;    // decrement i (e.g. i will equal 99, 98, 97,...)
    }

    d--;    // decrement d
}
}
```

I am still no clue how the number is calculated even looked at the comment...

Comment: Write the `delay` function, check the assembly code, and then check the documentation of the CPU to know how many cycles each instruction takes, and total the number of cycles for the loop (or loops). Then if you know how many cycles a piece of code takes, it's easy to calculate the value needed as argument when you have the clock-frequency (which decides the amount of cycles per second).

Comment: What chip are you programming for? Typically you would use some sort of interrupt to implement a delay.

Comment: Isn't there any hardware clock (with subsecond precision) you can query? Plain old busy-wait delay loops can be difficult and time consuming to tune. Are you compiling to the actual hardware or is it a simulator?

Comment: @FUZxxl I am programming for PIC32MX250F128B

Comment: @JoachimPileborg My chip is 32bit, and how do I look for the cycles in the datasheet? Is it different for each multiplication and division?

Comment: @Enzo Yes I am compiling to the actual hardware, I think the only source i could refer to is the data-sheet and semantic of the chip

Comment: You need to look for a programmers reference manual or similar, which contains all instructions supported. It will tell you the number of cycles each instruction takes. Such manuals are usually available for free.

Comment: you can go here: `https://www.microchip.com/TechDoc.aspx?type=ReferenceManuals` to obtain any available manual from microchip for any PIC varient

Comment: the instruction timings (number of clock cycles) is given in `http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39500a.pdf` in chapter 5.

Comment: it is determined experimentally against some time reference.

Answer (score 1):

The comment in the code in the OP seems to be unrelated to the actual code. 1190 is not used in the code.

Assuming the argument to `delay()` is milliseconds, I'd think the correct calculation would be 187.5 (cycles/millisecond )/ N (cycles/innerloop) = 187.5/N innerloops/millisecond. If N was 3 (cycles/innerloop), then that would be 62.5 innerloops/millisecond. or 62,500 innerloops/second. To come up with 1190 innerloops/sec, then N would need to be about 158. For the constant 100 in the code, then N would be 1.875.

The instruction set includes a DECFSZ instruction which decrements a register and then skips the instruction (by executing a NOP instead). If the inner loop were unrolled quite a bit, then the average instructions per inner loop would approach 2. But even in that case I'd think you want to use the value 187.5/2 = 94. Maybe there are some processor optimizations that reduce cycle counts by 6%. Or maybe delay() is calibrated to a 200KHz system clock.

It would be interesting to benchmark the delay routine to see how accurate it is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of such cycle count macros is that they are highly part (core type) specific, and that might cause you grief if you ever migrate to the 32MZ parts.

Most higher end (16,32-bit) Microchip parts have at least 5 configurable 16-bits timers that can be configured two-by-two as 32-bit timers.

Using such timers might allow you to derive the time directly from some CPU internal frequency (either core or peripheral), avoiding the need for "magic" numbers other than the relevant frequency per part (-family)

The block is also usually on some register flag to check for an interrupt flag, which means that only one loop is necessary which improves resolution.

I've no code for you since I only played with the 32-bit parts, and are more familiar with the 16-bit (dspic) parts, where this is part of the so called "peripheral library"

P.s. if you design a good delay function, it might be wise to also add a ClrWdt() or whatever resets the watchdog on PIC32 to the outer while loop.

Answer (score 0):

To programming a PIC32 I recommend to use the harmony framework from microchip. Then you can use the microchip harmony configurator to create a periodical timer that starts a callback function if the counter of the timer is zero. This method doesn't block the PIC and is easy to create..

I can give you an example if you need.

Answer (score 0):

In the libpic30.h you have the function:

```
void __delay32(unsigned long cycles);
```

Where cycles is the number of cycles to delay.

The minimum value for "cycles" is 12, this is specified in the "16-Bit Language Tools Libraries Reference Manual"